# Is there possible to write in a string words and use ate the same time %s as we do in printf()?

Tags: c

I am wondering is it possible to write in a string some content and put another string in there at the same time

```
char str[50], *test;
scanf("%s", str);
test = "123 %s 123", str;
printf("%s\n", test);
```

consider i write in the scanf "abc"

Is the a way for it to output:

- 123 abc 123

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to do `printf`-like formatting and put the result into character array.

```
char str[50], test[128];
scanf("%s", str);
snprintf(test, sizeof(test), "123 %s 123", str);
printf("%s\n", test);
```